# Quadratic differential equation - closed form solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, closed-form

Can a solution for x(t) be found from the following real valued differential equation

$$a\frac{d}{dt}\!(x(t))^2 + x(t) +b\frac{d}{dt}\!(y(t)) = 0$$

in terms of only y(t), it's integrals or derivatives and a, b ?

I tried using LaPlace operators to solve, but no luck.

Comment: What relation is there between $x(t)$ and $y(t)$? What does $\frac{d}{dt}(x(t))^2$ denote, exactly?

Comment: x and y are just real valued functions of time, bound by the mathematical expression in which they are written. The equation does represent a model of a physical system and there is causality such that x results in y, but as for the mathematics causality is not important.

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{2a}{b}\int x(t){dx(t)}+\dfrac{1}{b}\int x(t)dt=y(t)+C\\
\implies y(t)+C=\dfrac{a\times (x(t))^2+\int x(t)dt}{b}$$

Comment: Thanks, but nope, that's not what I was after. I'm looking for x(t) in terms of y(t) rather than the other way around. x(t) = ??